# Adding images to folder and save their name in database using php

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, mysqli

I am trying to upload 2 files in a folder and save their name and image path in database, here is my html code:

```
<input class="field2" type="file" name="file[]" multiple="multiple" />
```

and my php code is :

```
$i=0;
$count=0;             
     foreach ($_FILES['file']['name'] as $filename) 
     {
           if(file_exists('upload/'.$filename))
           {
               echo "That File Already Exisit";
               break;
           }
           else
           {
               $target='upload/';//folder path
               $tmp=$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$count];
               $count=$count + 1;
               $i=$i+1;

               $target=$target.basename($filename);
               move_uploaded_file($tmp,$target);
               $sql = "UPDATE `fleet` SET `image$i`='$target',`image_name$i`='$filename' WHERE id='$id' ";
               if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
               {
                   die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
               }
           }
       }
```

the issue is image is not getting stored in a folder, i have create a folder named upload, but nothing works foe me

Comment: So, you're following a tutorial?

Comment: yes, it was working before but not now, dont know what to do ?

Comment: Well, that's a very different kind of question. Amend your question accordingly, explaining what you were doing when it stopped working.

Comment: I did nothing, the question is why images are not getting stored in upload folder ??

Comment: No it isn't. The question is why are images no longer being stored in the upload folder.

Comment: well, i have used this code in other porject, it is working there fine, bt not here in my new project

Comment: Your use of $count and $i are interesting. Your table "fleet" has $i amount of columns named "image"+number?

Comment: Yes - I bet that bit's different in the working solution!

Comment: @VictorPerez yes my colum name are image1, image_name1, image2, image_name2

Comment: so, no one is helping me :/

Comment: Turn on errors and tell us what the server is telling you for that page. Put this on the top of your upload page: ini_set( "display_errors", 1 );

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this code:

```
<?php

$i=0;
$count=0;             
foreach ($_FILES['file']['name'] as $filename) 
{
    $upload_dir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/upload/";

    if(file_exists($upload_dir.$filename))
    {
        echo "That File Already Exist";
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        $tmp = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$count];
        $count++;
        $i++;

        $target = $upload_dir.basename($filename);

        if (is_dir($upload_dir) && is_writable($upload_dir)) {
            move_uploaded_file($tmp,$target);

            $sql = "UPDATE `fleet` SET `image$i`='$target',`image_name$i`='$filename' WHERE id='$id' ";
            if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
            {
                die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
            }
            } else {
            echo 'Upload directory is not writable, or does not exist.';
        }
}
```

If you have:

> Upload directory is not writable, or does not exist.

You should to a `chmod` or/and a `chown` command to give the permissions to write on the `upload_dir`.

Comment: Have you got Upload directory is not writable message ? Have you tried to put the full path of your upload folder in the upload_dir variable?

Comment: You can try to do a chmod -R +ax on your upload folder and a chown -R apache:apache on it.

Comment: chmod("upload/", 0755);

I use this but nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

instead of storing name in data base i am storing it in txt file(as per requirement)

```
<?php
 if (isset($_FILES["uploaded_file"]["name"])) {

$imagename=$_POST['imagename'];
$name = $_FILES["uploaded_file"]["name"];
$tmp_name = $_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'];
$error = $_FILES['uploaded_file']['error'];

if (!empty($name)) {
$location = './uploads/';

if ( ! is_dir($location)) {
    mkdir($location);
  }

if  (move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $location.$name)){
    echo 'Uploaded';    

    $fp = fopen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/myText.txt","a+");
    fwrite($fp,$imagename);
    fclose($fp);    
}
} else {
echo 'please choose a file';
}
}
?>
```